# Is “Love did compose” personification, or is it something else?

Tags: literary-techniques, rhetorical-devices

In Andrew Marvell’s poem [‘The Fair Singer’](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44681/the-fair-singer) he writes that *love did compose*:

> To make a final conquest of all me,
>   **Love did compose** so sweet an enemy,
>   In whom both beauties to my death agree,
>   Joining themselves in fatal harmony;
>   That while she with her eyes my heart does bind,
>   She with her voice might captivate my mind.

I am unsure what the term is for giving human traits to an abstract thing such as love, fear, and such. Is it personification or something else?

Comment: @NigelJ: Fear not: the rhyme scheme in this poem is ABABCC, which means that Marvell is not attempting what you suggest.

Comment: What has the rhyme scheme to do with it? Yes, I would say he is personifying Love, probably with an implied identification with the Roman god Cupid.